# Regenerate evolution scripts in play 2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I am still developing first version of my application on play 2. How could I regenerate evolution scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *it will destroy your existing database and create new one!*

The auto-evolution will auto-regenerate when:

- you are running your app in the `dev` mode
- in `application.conf` you have this line **not** commented : `ebean.default="models.*"`
- there is only one file in your evolutions folder and it's `1.sql`
- it has this comment at the beginning:

`# --- Created by Ebean DDL`

Comment: I found out the script only re-generates when I execute 'play test'. If I do 'play clean' or 'play compile', it wouldn't. Do you know what command is required to make evolution script re-generate?

Comment: @angelokh - sorry, I didn't find your comment before :? probably you found an answer after such a long time, however, of course re-generation works in `dev` mode only

Answer (score 0):

Using play 2.4, Slick 3.0.3 & postgres the *.sql files placed in the evolution folder were automatically generated in Heroku using the following setup:

in build.sbt:

```
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.3",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
```

in application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver ="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
```

and in Procfile:

```
-Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply = true
```

Cheers