# Scala Play 2.2 Slick 1.0.1 - future { Try {...} } Timed out waiting for a free available connection

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

I have a scala.html page that makes AJAX calls in a Play 2.2.1, Scala 2.10.2, Slick 1.0.1, Postgres 9.3 application.

The following synchronous code works fine. It parses the request query string and calls the method `Schools.findSchoolsByFilter`, which makes a scala slick call to a table and filters the results based upon the `SchoolFilter` object and returns a `Try[List[School]]`

```
def listSchools = Action { implicit request =>
  db.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
    Schools.findSchoolsByFilter(parseFilter) match {
      case Success(schools) => Ok(toJsArray(schools))
      case Failure(e) => Ok(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
```

If I change the method to run asynchronously (see below), and make multiple calls to listSchools, then after about 20 seconds this exception gets thrown. I suspect that it might be some sort of race condition akin to this post [Play slick and Async - is it a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579684/play-slick-and-async-is-it-a-race-condition). My question is, how should I change this code to safely run it asynchronously?

```
def listSchools = Action.async { implicit request =>
  db.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
    Schools.findSchoolsByFilter(parseFilter) map {
      case Success(schools) => Ok(toJsArray(schools))
      case Failure(e) => Ok(e.getMessage)
    }
  }
}
def findSchoolsByFilter(f: SchoolFilter, n: Int)(implicit s: Session) = 
  future { Try {
    ...
}}
case class SchoolFilter(name: Option[String], 
                        city: Option[String], 
                        state: Option[String],
                        zip: Option[String], 
                        district: Option[String])
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "slick-joda-mapper" % "0.4.0",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.0" % "test",
  "org.easymock" % "easymock" % "3.2",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4"
)
```

Here's the stack trace:

com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88)
com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90)
com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553)
com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131)
scala.slick.session.Database$$anon$1.createConnection(Database.scala:82)
scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(Session.scala:207)
scala.slick.session.BaseSession.conn(Session.scala:207)
scala.slick.session.Session$class.prepareStatement(Session.scala:29)
scala.slick.session.BaseSession.prepareStatement(Session.scala:201)
scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:29)
scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.elementsTo(StatementInvoker.scala:17)
scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.foreach(Invoker.scala:90)
scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.foreach(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.build(Invoker.scala:66)
scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.build(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
scala.slick.jdbc.Invoker$class.list(Invoker.scala:56)
scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.list(StatementInvoker.scala:10)
scala.slick.jdbc.UnitInvoker$class.list(Invoker.scala:150)
scala.slick.driver.BasicInvokerComponent$QueryInvoker.list(BasicInvokerComponent.scala:19)
models.school.Schools$$anonfun$findSchoolsByFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(School.scala:85)
models.school.Schools$$anonfun$findSchoolsByFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(School.scala:84)
scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
models.school.Schools$$anonfun$findSchoolsByFilter$1.apply(School.scala:84)
models.school.Schools$$anonfun$findSchoolsByFilter$1.apply(School.scala:84)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

### UPDATE

Per the recommendations of [Heroku/Play/BoneCp connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480506/heroku-play-bonecp-connection-issues), I added `"com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE"` to my library dependencies and the following to `application.conf` and am still getting the same behavior.

```
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 minutes
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=30 seconds
db.default.connectionTimeout=20 second
db.default.connectionTestStatement="SELECT 1"
db.default.maxConnectionAge=30 minutes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to open the session WITHIN the future. Right now you are doing the opposite. A Slick session is not valid after the end of the `withSession` block. If you open a future within the block it hangs on to the session even after the `withSession` block ended and the session became invalid. If the future code tries to use the invalid session you end up with unpredictable behavior.

Or in other words move the `db.withSession { implicit s: Session =>` call into the `future {...}` call.