# Play slick session connection timeout

Tags: scala, playframework, play-slick, slick-2.0

I'm having a problem with the session and connection handling in play with Slick 2.0.1 and play-slick 0.6.0.1

The error is

```
[SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.]
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
[...]
```

I have a play base controller trait for setting up the explicit session in one place

```
trait BaseController extends Controller with Secured {
    import play.api.Play.current
    implicit def session: SessionDef = play.api.db.slick.DB.withSession {
        implicit session => {session}
    }
}
```

Then there is the /list action with a simple call to a UserService using the explicit session:

```
object List extends BaseController with Secured {
  def index = IsAuthenticated { username =>
    implicit request =>
    UserService.findByEmail(username).map { user =>
      Ok(views.html.List.index(user))
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
  }
}
```

I have removed all async actions so I don't think this question would be a duplicate of similar questions: [Play slick and Async - is it a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579684/play-slick-and-async-is-it-a-race-condition) or [Scala Play 2.2 Slick 1.0.1 - future { Try {...} } Timed out waiting for a free available connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735410/scala-play-2-2-slick-1-0-1-future-try-timed-out-waiting-for-a-free-a?lq=1)

The issue occurs after reloading the action about 10 times.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong in the session handling of slick - are there any good examples of slick 2 session handling in playframework? What would be the best practice for that?

**edit:** One possible source of the issue *might* be an object that I use for holding the TableQueries

```
object Models {
    val users = TableQuery[Users]
    val mailinglists = TableQuery[Mailinglists]
    val mailinglistMemberships = TableQuery[MailinglistMemberships]
}
```

If that may be the source of the problem, what would be a good place to put these references? The main reason for the object is to reference these instances in the foreign keys of the table definition (similar to http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/schemas.html#constraints)

**edit:** Here's the code for findByEmail - but I don't think it really matters. It seems to be the same behavior and problem in all queries.

```
def findByEmail(email: String)(implicit session: Session): Option[User]
  = Models.users.filter(_.email === email).firstOption
```

I'd be thankful for any hint into the right direction.

Comment: How is `UserService.findByEmail(username)` implemented

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem.It seems like application not getting connection from connection pooling.so i have used configuration:

```
db.default.partitionCount=1  
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=20 
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=10 
db.default.acquireIncrement=1    
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=5 
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds 
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 minute 
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=5 minutes 
db.default.initSQL="SELECT 1" 
db.default.maxConnectionAge=1 hour
```

then never get error(Timed out waiting for a free available connection).(my application deployed on heroku with postgres database)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the implicit session definition in the `BaseController` trait. It seems that the session definition needs to be on the Action level and not on the controller level - unfortunately I can't explain the reason for that (yet).

```
trait BaseController extends Controller with Secured {
    //REMOVED this code
    //import play.api.Play.current
    //implicit def session: SessionDef = play.api.db.slick.DB.withSession {
    //    implicit session => {session}
    //}
}
```

Updated controller action using `DbAction` helped - not resulting in connection timeouts.

```
trait Application extends Controller {
  def index = DBAction { implicit request =>
    request.session.get("email") flatMap (email => UserService.findByEmail(email)) map { user =>
      Ok(views.html.index(user))
    } getOrElse {
      Ok(views.html.index(null))
    }
  }
}

object Application extends Controller with Application
```

So what is still missing is mixing an authenticated action with the `DBAction` of play-slick. The very same question has been asked here: [compose slick dbaction with authenticated action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710592/compose-slick-dbaction-with-authenticated-action)

Maybe someone of the slick/play-slick team can step in and answer these questions?