# Play Framework and Ebean: Error in trying to obtain a connection

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an Akka thread in my Play Framework application (hosted on Heroku) that gets called every 10 minutes. In this thread I access many models in my database in quick succession. After compiling and starting the application this thread runs fine for a few hours. Eventually (and for reasons unknown) the logger returns this:

```
c.j.b.PoolWatchThread - Error in trying to obtain a connection
```

My DB configuration (Heroku's PostgreSQL Basic plan) looks like this:

```
db.default.user=USER
db.default.password=PASS
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url=URL
db.default.partitionCount=2
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
db.default.maxConnectionAge=1 hour
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 minute
```

I have adjusted these variables without solving the problem.

Here is the stack trace

```
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]: [error] c.j.b.PoolWatchThread - Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 5000ms
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: too many connections for role "[DB USER NAME]"
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:469) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
2013-08-11T21:53:29.304108+00:00 app[web.2]:    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
```

I have a hunch it could be something to do with how and when I query the DB for the models. Like, maybe the connections are not released? Help is appreciated.

Edit:

More from the logger

```
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.TransactionManager.createQueryTransaction(TransactionManager.java:368)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.createQueryTransaction(DefaultServer.java:2060)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.OrmQueryRequest.initTransIfRequired(OrmQueryRequest.java:181)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findList(DefaultServer.java:1501)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.findList(DefaultOrmQuery.java:904)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.util.DefaultExpressionList.findList(DefaultExpressionList.java:177)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at models.Person.findByHandle(Person.java:85)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.257852+00:00 app[web.1]:    at models.NapalmJob.run(NapalmJob.java:41)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at models.NapalmActor.onReceive(NapalmActor.java:9)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:502)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:503)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:114)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin$WrappingDatasource.getConnection(EbeanPlugin.java:146)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.TransactionManager.createQueryTransaction(TransactionManager.java:338)
2013-08-13T14:43:49.258200+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 18 more
```

Queries are being formed but are not executed... Could some queries be taking longer to finish then others and thus not releasing the resources?

Answer (score 1):

This answer may help:
[Heroku POSTGRESQL - "Too many connections for role" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198911/heroku-postgresql-too-many-connections-for-role-error)

Also, are you overriding Play's default settings?

Comment: That solution has not prevented the error. Is it possible that connections are not being released? If so, where and how would that happen? I don't understand DB management so well, and this is my first foray into using Ebean... Hmm. What default settings do you mean? If the DB: yes.

Comment: Have you tried removing your configuration to see what happens when you default to the standard settings?

Comment: I will try the default settings now. However, I believe when the problem first occurred I only had the db connection params. I did not specify partitions or anything.

Comment: That didn't fix anything. It did return an interesting stack trace, though.

Comment: Have you looked on the play-framework google group? This seems like quite an interesting error.

Comment: Posted it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/alMbeQ1WpBw).