# Play Evolutions on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework

I'm using Play 1.2.4 on Heroku and I just reset my database so that I can switch from dev-mode/JPA to using prod-mode/evolutions.

However, I can not get the script to run.

I created my 1.sql file and put it in /db/evolutions. I set jpa.ddl to create so that it will initially create the tables and I checked to make sure it did that. When I run `play evolutions` from the CLI, I get the following:

> Cannot connected to the database : FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my_host", user "my_username", database "my_db", SSL off

When I try to do `heroku run "play evolutions:apply --%prod"` I get:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
~ Evolutions are not enabled. Create a db/evolutions directory to create your first 1.sql evolution script.
```

Do I need a pg_hba.conf file? In my application.conf I have:

```
db=${DATABASE_URL}
```

which is a heroku environment variable. I know that I don't have access to those locally so I tried copying the contents of the heroku variable to my local evironment variable $DATABASE_URL which I believe is what is being pulled from when I run `play evolutions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play#declare-dependencies), I added the db folder to my `.gitignore` file when I first created this project.

Removing it from there and recommitting to Heroku was what I had to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with git adding files, I think you have some problem with the database name definition. I posted my working evolutions config setup for play 2.4, Slick 3.0.3 & postgres. I got automatically generated the *.sql files placed in the evolution folder.

[Regenerate evolution scripts in play 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806926/regenerate-evolution-scripts-in-play-2/33438552#33438552)

Cheers