# Play Framework 2.1.1 deployment on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework-2.0

So I'm having a problem putting my play app on Heroku

Went through a couple of tutorials but couldn't get it to work.

My play app is getting displayed but the database for it is not getting created.

When I go through the logs this is coming

```
Database 'default' is in inconsistent state
....
Oops, cannot start the server.
.....
ERROR: syntax error at or near "auto_increment"
```

This is the configuration:

1. In application.conf all database lines are commented
2. `1.sql` is the same as normal (no changes)
3. Procfile is as follows

   ```
   web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true 
   -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
   ```

A shortened version of 1.sql is as follows (auto generated)

```
# --- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table admin (
    user_id                   bigint auto_increment not null,
    user_name                 varchar(255),
    user_username             varchar(255),
    user_password             varchar(255),
    user_privelege_level      integer,
    user_type                 integer,
    admin_id                  bigint,
    constraint pk_admin primary key (user_id))
;

# --- a lot more tables

alter table class add constraint fk_class_classteacher_1 foreign key (classteacher_user_id) references teacher (user_id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_class_classteacher_1 on class (classteacher_user_id);

# --- a lot more fks and indices

# --- !Downs

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
drop table admin;

drop table book;

# --- a lot more drops
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it done.

Apparently Heroku does NOT regenerate the evolution script (which doesn't really make sense)

Best option is to switch your development to POSTGRESQL

http://www.postgresql.org/download/

For anybody that might want some guidance on how to do that

1. Change Build.scala add the dependency

   ```
       "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
   ```
2. Change application.conf

   ```
     db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
     db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://servername:port/db_name"
     db.default.user=postgres
     db.default.password=pass
     # Remember to comment user and password while pushing because this will 
     # cause an error as Heroku doesn't automatically use theirs
   ```
3. Run the play app and allow the evolution to happen
4. Commit to the git, push it again and be happy.

Comment: Thanks! Stuck for hours and updating the driver solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an MySQL syntax.
Could you post your SQL? I suspect you use

```
INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

While you should use

```
SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: I'm not using anything explicitly. This is with the default 1.sql evolution generated by play. Is there anything (short of rewriting the whole evolution myself) that I can do . PS Question Edited

Comment: I'm not sure as I disabled evolution. I could be that in your case "Heroku" doesn't regenerate the evolution script and uses the MySQL version. Here's someone with a similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806926/regenerate-evolution-scripts-in-play-2, hope you can solve it I'm out of ideas.